# Cannot understand how to use Selenium WebDriverApi for Actions (click, send keys)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Use Selenium WebDriverApi
Try to use aclions at points: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#perform-actions

Get coordinates x, y by GET QUERY: "element/" + Element + "/rect"

Want to click at x, y.

But cannot understand, how do it in Web API.

All examples show as it do on usual Webdriver, f.e.:

```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
   action = ActionChains(driver)

   # Provide the URL of the website you want to visit.
   URL = 'https://www.testim.io/'
   driver.get(URL)

   # XPath of Images Hyperlink
   pricing_anchor_xpath = '//a[text()="Pricing"]'
   pricing_element = driver.find_element('xpath', pricing_anchor_xpath)
   action.move_to_element(pricing_element).click().perform()
```

How to get action by Web API?

Selenium Click an Sendkeys dont work on my HTML page, its protected, i try to use low-level events, like click and send keys

Comment: I think you should use `pricing_element.click()` to click of a tag, and use `input_field = driver.find_element(By.ID,ID) \ input_field.send()`

Comment: i know about click, clear & send keys, but i want to ty actions.
You write code by webdriver, but i use webdriver over API and cannot understand from its docs, how to send actions, there no expamle

Comment: I think you want actions = ActionChains(driver) first.  If click() isn't working it's likely you need to use WebDriverWaits, though.   You should try/catch your click() method to see what exception is being thrown.